# Marking axis in pgfplot

Tags: pgfplots

Welcome, I have this

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\newcommand\two[2]{#2*exp(#1)}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
 /pgf/number format/.cd,
 unit vector ratio*=1 10,
 width=12.5cm,
 every axis plot post/.append style={
 mark=none,domain=-20:20,
 },
 axis x line=bottom,
 axis y line=center,
 enlargelimits=upper
 ]
\addplot{\two{2}{1}};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

And what I want?
I want axis Y to be marked liked {6.5, 7.0, 7.5, 8.0, 8.5}
To be precise what I meant. Currently it is {6.5, 7, 7.5, 8, 8.5}
But I want axis X to be untouched.

Sorry for my somewhat bad English and THANKS from advance!

Thank you Paul! What's strange I actually tried something very similar yesterday, but with spaces in

```
yticklabel
```

like this

```
y tick label
```

Comment: Add the following to the axis options list: `yticklabel style={/pgf/number format/.cd,precision=1,fixed,fixed zerofill}`

Comment: So did @PaulGessler's comment solve your problem? If so, could you write an answer Paul?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To set the desired format for the y-axis labels, a few settings should be adjusted in the `yticklabel style` for the `axis` environment.

First, change "directories" into the location of the number formatting keys for convenience: `/pgf/number format/.cd`.

Next, set `precision=1` to change the precision for rounding operations.

Set the key `fixed` to display a fixed number of digits (the value of the `precision` key) after the decimal marker. This setting, by default, discards any trailing zeros.

Finally, set `fixed zerofill` to add trailing zeros to "fill" the number to the desired precision.

The complete additions required are as follows:

```
yticklabel style={/pgf/number format/.cd,precision=1,fixed,fixed zerofill},
```

### Code

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.10}

\newcommand\two[2]{#2*exp(#1)}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
  yticklabel style={/pgf/number format/.cd,precision=1,fixed,fixed zerofill},
  unit vector ratio*=1 10,
  width=12.5cm,
  every axis plot post/.append style={mark=none,domain=-20:20},
  axis x line=bottom,
  axis y line=center,
]
  \addplot{\two{2}{1}};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]